# 3 divs are not aligned

Tags: html, css

I make a forum and I have a problem :

[image]

Above work's good, but when I reduced the size of the page, here is the problem:

[image]

If i set to the text :

```
width:auto;
```

And to the parent :

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

It works but the `word-wrap: break-word;` doesn't work :(

I want the picture to be to the left with none of the text below it.

https://jsfiddle.net/39w1tkp2/1/

Comment: "it's work but the word-wrap: break-word; doesn't work :(" image : [Clic here](http://i.imgur.com/mTZt8iL.png)

Comment: Remove `white-space:nowrap;`.

Comment: salut , can you share a jsfiddle or ur codes pls

Comment: @PraveenKumar : The problem is even worse [clique here](http://i.imgur.com/0KqywBU.png)

Comment: @n01ze yes wait please

Comment: Create a fiddle and share with us buddy.

Comment: Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/39w1tkp2/ sorry image doesn't work

Comment: As an aside, your includes are all over the place - you have jQuery in head, which belongs just before closeing body tag, and a css include within your HTML, which belongs in head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the column left of the text where the avatar will lie, and no text below it simply...

```
.posttext{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display:block; // change to block
    padding-right:5px;
    width:auto; 
    padding-left: 120px; // pad left
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/39w1tkp2/2/)**

[image]

Comment: And can you explaine what changing a block element  to a block element does ? and define auto width a block element ? using padding for this is a solution but not very handy if you change something.. but (y)

Answer (score 2):

```
.posttext {

    display: inline; /*instead of inline-block*/

}
```

Because the width of div.posttext has not enough space to place the element.
If you change it to display: inline; (standard is block) it will have enough space to place it even between them.  find in [this link](http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/) too understand the difference is between block and inline..

**Edit:** user ask for more  solution #1
the img parent div: give a min-height of 400px; text will flow back to left after 400px;
[image]

**Edit:** user ask for more solution #2 (not fully tested yet, lack of available time atm i'm sorry))

```
.posttext {

    display: table; 

}
```

Comment: Now i have a probleme : here The text should not be in the red rectangle :/

Comment: @Derpolino i'll post serveral solutions :)

Comment: That still leaves text flowing into the left column, which it sounds like  should be empty. Padding on the text may be your friend.

Comment: i'm still adding solution, i don't know what askes wants and he is a newbie maybe he like back to left text..

Comment: @Derpolino solution #2  need more ? (i have 3 others, no so good ones) you shoud rewrite your htmlcode ;-)

Answer (score 1):

@Derpolino

Remove `display: inline-block` from class **posttext** and **userpost**

Comment: And what has userpost class to do with answer ?

Comment: Now i have a probleme : [here](http://i.imgur.com/kSex6Vo.png)
The text should not be in the red rectangle :/

Comment: @Derpolino it would be better if you described exactly the expected result in the first place, then contributors could give a correct answer.